# passport Unknown authentication strategy "local", "facebook", "google"

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, token

I'm building a register system where a user can login with Facebook, Google, or locally.

Whenever I post via any login strategy I get uknown strategy error. I think I did connect all files all together.
I did check every solution, on stackoverflow, but can't find anything that could help aht the moment.

My code:
https://github.com/ExadelPraktika/Back-exabook/tree/backend_full

Comment: Check your switch(strategy) logic, looks like when you are sending the chosen strategy, its not coming in the format you expect. Maybe a case sensitive issue.

Comment: Also, you just need to post code which is directly relevant to the challenge, full repo won;t be cloned due to sheer effort required

Comment: Hello, could you please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve on how to add example to your questions. So please extract the part of the source code that produce the error, give in your post all the needed informations (versions of node, of the passport library, etc.). Please add also the exact error you receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added 
require('../passport');
in passport.js
it works

Answer (score 0):

You will also get this error if the strategy is not passed to the use command like so:

```
passport.use("google", strategy);
```